# Getting Double Quotation Marks in Write-Host Output

Tags: powershell

I need to get some double quotations around the GUID=$ntds output.  I have tried encompassing the entire string in double quotes to no avail.  Single quotes won't work because of the variable.

```
$Site=Read-Host "ENTER SITE NAME"
$Server=Read-Host "ENTER SERVER NAME"


$NTDS=Get-ADObject -Identity "CN=NTDS Settings,CN=$server,CN=Servers,CN=$site,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,$((Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName)" |foreach {$_.objectguid} 
write-host "Repadmin /showobjmeta" * "<GUID=$ntds>"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use another pair of double quotes to escape like

```
Write-Host "hello ""200mg"""
```

Which will output `hello "200mg"`

Your case it would be

```
write-host "Repadmin /showobjmeta""<GUID=$ntds>"""
```

Comment: See http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html for more info on escaping characters in Powershell.

Comment: Close the output shows the last double quotes but not the first pair before <GUID..........  Repadmin /showobjmeta * <GUID=66402bcf-36fa-42a4-91d3-5c3ef264d52f>"

Comment: @200mg, try it exactly in my answer. remove that `*` character altogether

Comment: the * is necessary in the command, i figured out a work around though using the escape chararcter...thanks for all the help..write-host "Repadmin /showobjmeta" * `"<GUID=$ntds>`"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know powershell, but from other languages,  you can try:

you can try using double-double quote "" where you want to have ".

```
"<GUID=""$ntds"">"
```

or you can try single quotes if permitted on the outside

```
'<GUID="$ntds">'
```

or you can try the backslash as escape character before the " making it

```
"<GUID=\"$ntds\">"
```

Just try and let me know if you succeeded.